# Linking boost Filesystem and Serialisation libraries in MSVC in a mixed-mode C++-CLI project

Tags: .net, visual-c++, boost, mixed-mode

I try to use C++-CLI in Visual Studio 2013 to create a GUI. My project use a C++ lib this lib use Boost Filesystem and Serialisation libraries, but I get the following linker error:

```
visual c++ error lnk1104 cannot open file 'boost_serialization-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.lib'
```

When I comment the include of serialisation header I get the same error for the filesystem lib.

When I comment both include lines I get no error with (so the the other boost libs work)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying the problem is: that it shouldn't need that lib? Do you have that lib, and have you told Visual Studio where to find it?

Comment: "when i comment the both ligne i've no error with the others boost lib" — either there's a typo in there, or that means the problem went away already.

Comment: To be honest it looks like this is completely unrelated to C++-CLI /cc @PaulR

Comment: @sehe: sorry - I thought Managed C++ was CLI ? I'm not that familiar with the Microsoft world though - I'll delete the tag.

Comment: @PaulR It is. But the error is unrelated to that, AFAICT (I just CC-ed you)

Comment: Oh I see - no problem either way - I am happy to defer to you on this as I don't have a lot of exposure to Windows etc.

Comment: @Potatoswatte no typo there i've create un other c++/cli project and i've created un other lib with just the boost header(include) on the 10 included header only the filesystem and serialisation trow that error

Comment: @NaseefUrRahman the problem is not solved, but i don't have much time to spend on that project

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is straightforward. Do you have provided input library **boost_serialization-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.lib** in the **Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies** option. You need to put your lib in there. Please make sure. You can get help from the following snap shot - [image]

The snap shot above will help you to find the option from Visual Studio. Just go to project properties then you will see something like this. Go to **Linker->Input** and provide the required libs in **Additional Dependencies**. Then you are done.

**EDIT:**
As **Sehe** mentioned lib inputs are automatically handled by boost using #pragma lib. If you are using this, you just need to set the **Library Directories**. Library Directories can be set by going to Project Properties. If you go to Project Property you will find a tab named **VC++ Directories** and if you click on the tab you will find **Library Directories** option along with other directory options. The following figure may help you on this - 
[image]

You just need to put the library directory of the boost library there.

Comment: Actually the lib inputs are automatically handled by boost using `#pragma lib` (this explains the linker error in the first place). The important part is the library directories. Perhaps you can add this to the answer to make it useful (or link to the existing answers, I have no time to find it)

Comment: Edited! Is it helpful now?

Comment: in my unmanaged lib yes it's done but the managed app don't need the lib no ?

Comment: @gregory you *still* have to link against it if your unmanaged lib depends on it.

Comment: @Lucas boost can't be linked directly in the cli project "incompatible  metadata "